# How to fetch values from a dictionary when some its keys are dynamically change

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

I have one Mutable Array with 20 objects.Each object have the given format

```
{

 "NONE-NONE-ABCD-RECD" =     {
  Count =         
        {
              bird = "10";
              animal = "4";
        };

  Type = "NONE-NONE-ABCD-RECD";
};

}
```

The key `NONE-NONE-ABCD-RECD` will be different for different objects.Some times become **NONE-NONE-NONE-NONE** or **ABCD-PQWE-MNBW-POWE**,etc. I need the bird found and animal found of the each objects.How can i get the counts when keys changes.

Comment: I don't see why the `Type` entry is there, given it's the same as the top-level dictionary key.  Removing it and relying on the top-level key is the quickest way of finding the entries.  Also it looks like those `Count` dictionary entries should be numbers, not strings...

Comment: Will what's in `Type` be the `key`? Else, you can iterate and get key of a `NSDictionary`, if you always wait for a subdictionary with `count` key for example.

Comment: @trojanfoe.I am working in the client side actually its coming from severside.This format is need for their web developement

Comment: So you are saying you have no influence on how this data is stored in the "client side"?

Comment: @Larme I am new in object C would you please help me to solve this.Give some solution as like code.

Comment: @user3564078, what code do you demand from us? can you post, please, the real stucture of the data you receive? that tiny fragment gives very ambiguous picture of your actual data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
NSArray *allKeys = [elementDict allKeys]; //elementDict array object
if ([allKeys count] > 0) {
    NSDictionary *objectDict = [elementDict objectForKey:[allKeys objectAtIndex:0]];
    NSDictionary *countDict = [objectDict objectForKey:@"Count"];
    //from countDict you can access values
    NSString *bird = [countDict valueForKey:@"bird"];
    NSString *animal = [countDict valueForKey:@"animal"];
}
```

Comment: i have one more doubts.I set one predicate with some condition.If the condition will fail what will return? anything like null or empty string?

Comment: @user3564078 It will return an array with 0(zero) objects, if the condition not match with any element in array.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if `Type` will everytime returns your the `key`, you can do this:

```
NSString *yourKey = [yourDictionary objectForKey:@"Type"];
NSDictionary *countDict = [yourDictionary objectForKey:yourKey];
int bird = [[countDict objectForKey:@"bird"] intValue];
int animal = [[countDict objectForKey:@"animal"] intValue];
```

Other solution:

```
for (NSString *aKey in yourDictionary)
{
    if ([[yourDictionary objectForKey:@"aKey"] isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
    {
        NSDictionary *countDict = [yourDictionary objectForKey:aKey];
        int bird = [[countDict objectForKey:@"bird"] intValue];
        int animal = [[countDict objectForKey:@"animal"] intValue];
    }
}
```

Other solution, according if your object may contain other sub-dictionary:

```
for (NSString *aKey in yourDictionary)
{
    if ([[yourDictionary objectForKey:@"aKey"] objectForKey:@"Count"])
    {
        NSDictionary *countDict = [[yourDictionary objectForKey:@"aKey"] objectForKey:@"Count"];
        int bird = [[countDict objectForKey:@"bird"] intValue];
        int animal = [[countDict objectForKey:@"animal"] intValue];
    }
}
```